# Where to download FaceBook JavaScript SDK and xd_receiver.htm

Tags: facebook

I have experience with PHP and JavaScript, but am new to using the FaceBook API.  I'm carefully reading through the documentation, but notice thta  lot of links within their documentation are broken.  For example, the link for http://api.facebook.com/static/xd_receiver.htm is broekn and I need that content to be able to do almost anything with the FB API.  Seriously, these guys seem to have really dropped the ball with their documentation.  Does anyone know where I can get this file and the rest of the JavaScript SDK?  Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see the broken link in the documentation? if you provide a link here I'll see if we can get it fixed to point to the correct location

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
</script>
```

The contents of the `channel.html` file should be this single line:

```html
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Here is the direct link that should help with this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#loading

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily download it yourself so much as load it when you want to use it.

Here's a link to the quickstart

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.0

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the documentation that facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) has for their Javascript SDK. There are some areas that are poor (to put it lightly), but most of it is there, or in the comments/forums created by users