# Facebook "GET https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" giving ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I tried the sample code which was provided by Facebook at [Quickstart guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)
and I am geting the following response:

> GET https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

The following is my source code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>FBTestDrive</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'I got the app id.',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried putting **http/https** before **//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js** and I am also running the application from a server (local Apache Tomcat web server) but nothing is working.

Comment: are you trying to do this in an iframe?

Comment: Yes. Both. In an iframe and directly in a browser

Comment: Could the reason be that the source is no longer working?
Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165143/where-to-download-facebook-javascript-sdk-and-xd-receiver-htm

Answer (score 0):

<sub>In case someone else finds this question:</sub>

I have seen this error appear when IT departments are blocking access to Facebook. The request to `connect.facebook.net` (or any `facebook.net` or `facebook.com` address) will be intercepted by the corporate proxy, and a `403 Forbidden` response will be returned instead.